# Lazy loading controllers that are in different modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, lazy-loading, amd

I am building a large Angular Application. I am trying to lazy load dependencies.
So my application module in app.js looks like

```
testApp = angular.module('SellerDashboard', [
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ngRoute',
        'chieffancypants.loadingBar',
        'ngAnimate',
        'route-segment', 
        'view-segment',
        'Feature1.Index',
        'Feature1.My_Listings',
        'Feature1.My_Listings.Directives',
        'Feature2.Debug',
        'Feature2.Index',
        'Feature3.Index',
        'Feature3.Landing'
    ]);
```

Each of these modules have sub modules which has further dependencies.Each of the modules are in seperatefiles .An example file is as follows

```
var featureApp = angular.module('Feature1.My_Listings', ['Feature1.Services', 'Common.Services', 'CommonDebug.Services','angular-intro']);

listing_app.controller('my_listing', ['$scope', 'fkPaginator', '$routeParams', 'fkLogger', '$q','fkLoaderManager',function ($scope,fkPaginator, $routeParams, fkLogger, $q,fkLoaderManager) { //do somesthing})]);
```

So my app.js has no direct dependency on 'Feature1.Services' modules. It has dependency of Feature1.My_Listings module (which defines the controllers) which has further dependency on services modules.

[Feature1.Services defines the services has further dependency on other providers its requires]

Now,I do not want my Feature1.My_Listings to be loaded until I go the page that actually require some controller defined in 'Feature1.Services' .So if I am in "My_Listings" page I do not want to load fFeature2 and Feature 3 modules.

[Implement lazy loading](http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/) . The above link shows how to use resolve while changing routes.But then it also makes it mandatory to have all files under one module which is the app module and all controllers to be defined as app.controller("bla bla") using app as the global variable. But in my case I want to lazy load modules and include them dynamically based on the routes.

How do I go about it ?? It would be nice if somebody could help regarding how this can be achieved using requirejs.

So for a very large app is the above way correct for defining controllers,services ,etc or breaking them in to smaller modules like I did is the proper way ??

Comment: Here is a project that does lazy loading with requirejs: [require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/require-lazy). This works fairly well. I am in the progress of integrating with angular [here](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy/) and you can get some ideas. But angular-require-lazy is far from being complete (thus this is only a hint, not a real answer). However ideas or comments are always wellcome.